# Should the overlay or tooltip text for voting arrows be changed?

Tags: feature-request, voting, user-interface, meta

Right now, the text that pops up when you hover the pointer over the voting arrows is identical to the main site, like this:

[image: overlay text in meta for vote arrows]

Problem is, the text that pops up when you hover over the vote arrows is incorrect for meta. Both up and down arrows display the wrong message.

That example question above shows research effort, is clear, and is useful. I just disagree with the point so want to downvote it. This is best explained in the '[What does voting mean here](http://meta.askubuntu.com/faq#vote-differences)' part of the meta FAQs, but contradicted by the overlay text.

**Can it be changed, and if yes should it be?**

*And speaking of research effort, I tried searching for a dupe of this here and was surprised to not find any ([except on Meta SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75049/change-upvote-downvote-tooltip-on-meta-sites)). Either my search-fu is weakening or nobody has complained about this yet.*

Comment: Nobody on AU has complained, but Jeff Atwoods answer on that is still law. http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/104398/156713

Comment: @jrg is it forbidden then, or just a situation where nobody wants to do it for another reason? The linked question was quite popular, with Jeff's 'no' answer downvoted. I thank you for your comment but I'm unclear on what you mean by 'law' *(e.g. is it social pressure or an absolute rule)*

Comment: Absolute rule until the matter is taken up again by popular demand.